# Unity Particle System

Tags: unity3d, камера, particles

Я в скрипте прописал изменение позиции партиклов к нажатому месту, все работает партиклы изменяют свое положение в нажатую точку, но проблема в том, что после изменения позиции незавершенные свой цикл партиклы тоже изменяют свое положение. Я не хочу делать это через Pool или Спавн префаба, так что, есть ли другой вариант, решения проблемы?

Вот сам скприт:

```
public void Click()
    {
        PS.gameObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, PS.gameObject.transform.position.z));
            PS.Play();
        anim.SetTrigger("Click");
        playerInfo.Coins += playerInfo.clickMoneyS;
        Refrash(playerInfo.Coins, coinsText);
    }
```